# Catch Entity Validation Errors in Webforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms, entity-framework-6

I would like to catch validation errors based on the attributes I have set in my models and display them in a validation summary control. I was going to use the ModelState.IsValid function however my EF functions are in business layer in a separate class and are called from UI code behind. Is there a way to capture all validation errors when performing a call such as the following that I could then pass back to the UI behind code?

Behind Code:

```
...
person.AddPerson(person)
...
```

BLL:

```
Public Shared Function AddPerson(person As Person) As Boolean
        Using db As Context = New Context
            db.Persons.Add(person)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return True
        End Using
    End Function
```

Thanks -

Comment: Your UI should be able to reference the annotated models. You could also look at this: http://davalidation.codeplex.com/

Comment: That looks very promising, I'll test it out and report back, Thanks!